# Adding object to an array is not refreshing ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are list of attractions , and when user selects those items will goto a selected list,

```
app.controller('ItineraryNewController', function($scope) {
$scope.city = "";
$scope.attractions =[];
$scope.places = [] ;
$scope.day = 1;
$scope.getAttractions=function(){

        $scope.attractions.push({
        name: "LA",
            description: "test la",
              address: "3423 some stree",
              website: "test.com"
          },,
          {
        name: "SFO",
            description: "test SFO",
              address: "3423 some stree",
              website: "testsfo.com"
          });

}
$scope.addPlace = function(place,index){
  console.log(index);
    $scope.places.push($scope.attractions[index]);
}
```

The places is not updating , i see the index value as undefined.

The example is posted in plunker, [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X58Wot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass the correct number of arguments to your function `addPlace` from the template.

From your function definition `addPlace(place, index)`

### This

```
<button ng-click="addPlace($index)">Add</button>
```

### Should be

```
<button ng-click="addPlace(place, $index)">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks , i forgot to save it , thought plunker has auto save. The link in question is correct now, as i removed attractionService. do you have an idea why it is not working

Comment: Sure update your question please because I'm not quite sure of what you want to achieve

Comment: if you look at link now , press Get List and then click on Add , i dont see the list updating